Unitary representation of a discrete group as a sum of cyclic representations
A cyclic representation on a Hilbert space is one where there exists a vector such that, under the action of the representation, this vector spans the entire Hilbert space.
It is known that every C*-representation on a Hilbert space is a Hilbert space direct sum of cyclic representations (see for example Proposition 2.23 at 208 C*-algebras).
Is it true that every unitary representation of a discrete group is a direct sum of cyclic representations?

Yes, and the proof is the same, you imitate the construction of an orthonormal basis. Pick any nonzero vector, consider the cyclic representation it generates, take the orthogonal complement, repeat...
